# solving complicated complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Find values for $a$ and $b$ so that $z=a+bi$ satisfies $\displaystyle \frac{z+i}{z+2}=i$. Below are my workings:

so far i simplify $\displaystyle \frac{z+i}{z+2}=i$ to $z=zi+i$

which $a=i$, $b=z$

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are supposed to be real numbers, not $i$ nor $z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{z+i}{z+2}=i\\
\implies a=-b\mbox{ and }\\
\mbox{}b+1=a+2\mbox{ (by taking the imaginary and real parts of the resulting equation.)}$$
Solving gives
$$\boxed{b=0.5,a=-0.5}$$

Comment: how do you ge4t a=-b and b+1=a ?

Comment: @harry As I've said, you can use the real and imaginary parts of the equation you get when you write $z+i=iz+2i$.

Comment: what? how can u sub z+i=iz+2i into another equation

Comment: So, let me multiply it out: $a+bi+i=ia-b+2i$. Take the real and imaginary part - and you get the desired equations.

Comment: what do u do from now?

Comment: As I've said, solve for $b,a$ by taking the real and imaginary parts of $a+bi+i=ia-b+2i$.

Comment: oh Thanks~ i solve it

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You have $\frac {z+i}{z+2}=i$  Multiplying by $z+2$ gives $z+i=iz+2i$  Now substitute in $z=a+bi$, remembering that $a$ and $b$ are real.  The real and imaginary parts give you two equations in the two unknowns $a,b$

Comment: substitute z=iz+i into z=a+bi ?

Comment: No, substitute $a+bi$ for $z$ in the previous equation.  It becomes $a+bi+i=i(a+bi)+2i$

Comment: wait how can u do that?

Comment: @harry  Algebra still works the same way for complex numbers as it does for reals.  The added "feature" is that inserting $ \ z = a + bi \ $ into the algebraic equation $  \ z + i \ = \ iz + 2i \ $ produces real and imaginary parts on both sides of the equation, which must be "matched up" separately.  (We do this with real-number algebra all the time: we just don't think about it as "making parts agree" because the "imaginary part" is always zero...)

Answer (score 1):

$z=zi+i$ is equivalent to $z-zi=i$.
$z(1-i)=i$ then $z=\frac{i}{1-i}$ so $a = Re(z)$ and $b=Im(z).$